# Perpendicular vectors and magnitude

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

> Consider the vectors $\binom{-1}{x}$ and $\binom{2x}{e^{0.5ln(X)}}$. Find the values for x that ensure that these vectors are perpendicular, given that the magnitude of the vector $\binom{2x}{e^{0.5ln(X)}}$ is $\sqrt{68}$.

Using dot product for $\binom{-1}{x}$ and $\binom{2x}{e^{0.5ln(X)}}$, I got x=0 and x=4, but I don't understand what $\binom{2x}{e^{0.5ln(X)}}$ being $\sqrt{68}$ has anything to do with the answer. Is it significant, and if so, why, and how can I use it for my answer?

Comment: The magnitude restriction rules out one of the possibilities $x=0$ and $x=4$.

Comment: There is a logarithm , so x is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

the magnitude of the second vector is

$$m=\sqrt {(2x)^2+(e^{0,5\ln (x)})^2}=$$
$$\sqrt {4x^2+e^{\ln (x)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt {4x^2+x} $$

$$=\sqrt {68} $$ if $x=4$.